# SQL Query for calculating Turnover Rate over rolling period

Tags: sql, sql-server

**EDIT:** I completely re-edited this question. Hopefully with the information requested in the comments section. This is my first time posting a question here, so I apologize for missing and forgetting to include so many important details. I almost asked another question on how to format this right...

Tables:

```
TABLE [Facility]
[ID]             [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Site]           [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ContractID]     [int] NULL,


TABLE [Employees]

[ID]             [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Payroll]        [nvarchar](6) NULL
[LastName]       [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[HomeStation]    [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[WorkLocation]   [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DateOfHire]     [datetime] NULL,
[TermDate]       [datetime] NULL,
[Status]         [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[HomeStationID]  [int] NULL,
[ContractID]     [ContractID] [int] NULL,
```

If I select those tables from each, an example output would be the following:

Facility:

| ID | Site | ContractID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Camp Lucas | 8 |
| 2 | Fort Sixty | 8 |
| 3 | Double Trouble | 8 |
| 4 | Camp Lemmons | 8 |
| 5 | Camp Appletrees | 8 |
| 6 | Fort Example | 8 |
| 8 | Base Doctor | 8 |
| 9 | Lab Test 16 | 9 |
| 10 | McDonalds | 9 |
| 11 | McStinky | 9 |
| 13 | Nebraska LCL | 9 |
| 14 | Camp Structured | 9 |
| 16 | Fort SevenEleven | 9 |
| 17 | Fort RobertK | 9 |
| 18 | Ride Bard | 9 |
| 19 | Camp IdleUser | 9 |
| 20 | Burger King | 9 |

Employees:

| ID | PAYROLL | LastName | HomeStation | WorkLocation | DateOfHire | TermDate | Status | HomeStationID | ContractID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000001 | CARTWRIGHT | McStinky | McStinky | 1999-12-27 00:00:00.000 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 11 | 9 |
| 4 | 000002 | LAMBERT | Nebraska LCL | Nebraska LCL | 2000-01-14 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ACTIVE | 13 | 9 |
| 5 | 000003 | SANTOS | Fort RobertK | Fort RobertK | 2001-08-03 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ACTIVE | 17 | 9 |
| 6 | 000004 | PARKER | Burger King | Burger King | 2000-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ACTIVE | 8 | 9 |
| 9 | 000007 | SLAYDEN | Lab Test 16 | Lab Test 16 | 2000-04-28 00:00:00.000 | 2017-03-10 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 9 | 8 |
| 10 | 000008 | ROSADO | Camp Structured | Camp Structured | 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 14 | 1 |
| 11 | 000009 | RIDER | Nebraska LCL | Nebraska LCL | 2016-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 2019-04-08 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 13 | 3 |
| 12 | 000010 | PENA | McDonalds | McDonalds | 2000-06-12 00:00:00.000 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 10 | 9 |
| 13 | 000011 | SAMUEL | Ride Bard | Ride Bard | 2008-08-07 00:00:00.000 | 2015-10-29 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 18 | 9 |
| 14 | 000012 | CHERRIX | Fort SevenEleven | Fort SevenEleven | 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2013-07-30 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 16 | 9 |
| 15 | 000013 | JONES | Ride Bard | Ride Bard | 2000-08-29 00:00:00.000 | 2013-01-07 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 18 | 9 |
| 16 | 000014 | LOMENT | Burger King | Burger King | 2000-10-11 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ACTIVE | 20 | 9 |
| 17 | 000015 | SCHWARZ | Camp Structured | Camp Structured | 2005-07-24 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ACTIVE | 14 | 9 |
| 18 | 000016 | GAME | Nebraska LCL | Nebraska LCL | 2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-07-13 00:00:00.000 | INACTIVE | 13 | 9 |

That is example output. The tables contain a few thousand records in total with both dates of hire and termination dates up to today.

*Everything was fine when I was collecting less data*. For example the below query: For each site, the active numbers at the start of 2020, followed by the terminations through 2020, followed by my end total active going into 2021.

```
SELECT
   F.[SITE]
  ,F.[ContractID]
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN E.[DateOfHire] <= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
      AND E.[Status] = 'Active' THEN 1 END) AS 'ACTIVE AT START OF 2020'

   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN E.[Status] = 'Inactive'
      AND E.[TermDate] > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
      AND E.[TermDate] < '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 1 END) AS 'Terminated Employees IN 2020'
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN E.[DateOfHire] <= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       AND E.[Status] = 'Active' THEN 1 END) AS 'ACTIVE AT START OF 2021'

    FROM [websvr].[dbo].[Employees] AS E
      INNER JOIN [websvr].[dbo].[Facility] AS F
         ON E.HomeStationID = F.ID
    WHERE F.[ContractID] = 9
   GROUP BY F.[Site], F.[ContractID];
```

That query would output like this:

| SITE | ContractID | ACTIVE AT START OF 2020 | Terminated IN 2021 | ACTIVE AT START OF 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lab Test 16 | 9 | 5 | 7 | 10 |
| McDonalds | 9 | 48 | 11 | 52 |
| McStinky | 9 | 144 | 242 | 180 |
| Camp Structured | 9 | 17 | 0 | 18 |
| Nebraska LCL | 9 | 27 | 42 | 31 |
| Fort SevenEleven | 9 | 9 | 1 | 12 |
| Fort RobertK | 9 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| Ride Bard | 9 | 10 | 4 | 12 |
| Camp IdleUser | 9 | 5 | 1 | 7 |
| Burger King | 9 | 39 | 25 | 49 |
| FILLER 1 | 9 | 100 | 71 | 115 |
| FILLER 2 | 9 | 287 | 99 | 301 |
| FILLER 3 | 9 | 38 | 9 | 97 |
| FILLER 4 | 9 | 9 | 6 | 33 |
| FILLER 5 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| FILLER 6 | 9 | 10 | 2 | 14 |
| FILLER 7 | 9 | 13 | 4 | 40 |

**You might have noticed none of these examples include a turnover rate column (defined below).** That's because I initially intended to calculate the rate with Power Bi after I pulled the correct columns to even calculate the turnover rate. I messed up with the title to this question, I should have specified that I only need to get the columns required to calculate this field. Anyways, I've now been told I need to be able to calculate the turnover at the end of each month in addition to an annual turnover. Is this even possible in a single query? So my query above let's me do the annual rate, sorta... But, how can I get the columns needed for the turnover rate on a monthly basis along with the year AND per site? *Also, the starting period is 2020-01-01 through the current date.* It only needs to go back as far as the first of 2020.

**To calculate the turnover, I intended to do this**: *(terminations in a month / my total number of active employees at the end of that month) * *100*

But, I've struggled to get a query that actually outputs data correctly. Because, my assumption is that I need to select: *Active employees at the start of 2020, number of active employees at the start of the month, the hires within a month, the terminations within a month, total active at the end of a month, total active at the end of the year, and the total terminated through the year*. (I think that's everything needed to get my data)

I have no idea how to approach this.

**EDIT: Upon further review based on Nick.McDermaid's reply**, I think separating the year and monthly rates would be ideal. So two separate queries is the right move. The yearly one I can handle easily, but for the monthly one I can't figure out how to calculate the active number at the start and end of a month. How can I define these two values exact values?

**EDIT again**, I will use a calendar table on the SQL side. This concept is new to me, if anyone has any education/learning resources that will help explain the logic involved in connecting this to my existing dataset to help me get the columns I need I'd appreciate it. Or any other advice on approaching this issue.

*Those columns being*: Active employees at the start of 2020, number of active employees at the start of the month, the hires within a month, the terminations within a month, total active at the end of a month, total active at the end of the year, and the total terminated through the year

**EDIT: Currently testing this:** huge thanks to Nick McDermaid. I'll update this as I go.

```
    DECLARE @Calendar table
    (
        [CalendarDate] DATETIME
    )
    
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
    SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
    
    WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
          BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO @Calendar
                 (
                       CalendarDate
                 )
                 SELECT
                       @StartDate
    
                 SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @StartDate)
          END
    
    SELECT CalendarDate AS 'Date'
    FROM @Calendar
```

**EDIT:** CURRENTLY Testing this per a solution by Nick McDermaid. Big thanks to him.

**EDIT:** It was my dataset. A large amount of employees were trying to be retrieved, which caused the processing time to take a very long time. I was terminating it before it was over. Also, I forgot to include my where clause to filter the contractid.

```
GO

DECLARE @Calendar table
 (
     [CalendarDate] DATE,
     CalendarMonth VARCHAR(7),
     IsSOM bit,
     IsEOM bit,
     IsSOY bit,
     IsEOY bit
 )

 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
 DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
 SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
 SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

 WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO @Calendar
             (
                    CalendarDate,
                    CalendarMonth,
                    IsSOM,
                    IsEOM,
                    IsSOY,
                    IsEOY
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate,
                   FORMAT(@StartDate,'yyyy-MM'),
                   CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,@StartDate)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsSOM,
                   CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate))=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsEOM,
                   CASE WHEN FORMAT(@StartDate,'ddMM')='0101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsSOY,
                   CASE WHEN FORMAT(@StartDate,'ddMM')='3112' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsEOY

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @StartDate)
END


SELECT
C.CalendarMonth,
E.[Homestation],
-- When calculating Headcount at end of month,
-- only consider a record on the end of the month
SUM(CASE WHEN IsEOM=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EOMHeadcount,

-- Similar logic for start of month
SUM(CASE WHEN IsSOM=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOMHeadcount,

-- To count Terminations, only count records
-- on days that there was a termination
SUM(CASE WHEN C.CalendarDate = E.TermDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PeriodTerminations,

-- Similar logic for Hires
SUM(CASE WHEN C.CalendarDate = E.DateOfHire THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PeriodHires
FROM
@Calendar C
LEFT JOIN
[websvr].[dbo].[Employees] AS E
ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN E.DateOfHire AND IIF(E.TermDate = '1900-01-01','2100-01-01',E.TermDate)
 
GROUP BY C.CalendarMonth, E.[Homestation]
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you mean by "employee turnover" would all. improve the question.

Comment: A pet peeve, but the semi-colon (`;`) is a statement **terminator**, it goes at the *end* of all your statements, not the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated as well, so you're far better off getting into the good habit of terminating them now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Employee Turnover will be calculated with my (terminations in a month / my total number of active employees at the end of that month) *100. Those conditions should also apply to the year.

Comment: So for the yearly figure the denominator is the active employees at the end of December?Or do you want a rolling yearly figure calculated for every month? This is why it is important that you show a sample output recordset.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm sorry. This is my first time posting to Stackoverflow. I've got tunnel vision and It's made me absent minded, so I've forgotten to include a lot of necessary detail. To answer your question, yes. It would be the total active up to the end of that month.

Comment: I'm sorry you're struggling with tunnel vision. Please help us by making it really easy to see what you're asking - please avoid pasting (links to) images. Instead, please post text showing sample data, expected results from that sample data, and the logic to retrieve those results, in the question. Reading a trail of comments to figure things out is hard.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I completely reworded and formatted the original question. Does the data I've added help clarify everything? I'm worried I might have misunderstood what everyone meant by sample data. I can add more if need be to the post.

Comment: Thanks for returning with more details. These HR type queries can be tricky. For _any_ kind of rate yes you should always feed the drivers and let the reporting tool calc the rate. Then you can aggregate it properly (i.e. find the correct rate over all facilities). With regards to mixing up yearly and monthly rates: how does it need to be visualised?  If it doesn't need to be on the same chart/table then two seperate queries is probably fine. I know that DAX (Power BI query language) is perfect for this type of thing so it might be worth investigating in that direction.

Comment: You will need to create a dataset that is unqiue on facility and _month_, and have these kinds of columns (from your question): active employees at start of period, hires within period, terminations within period, active at the end of period. Put those into Power BI,visualise it,  then see if it makes sense to try and include yearly figures in that query or not (it can be done if required). To generate that dataset you will need a _calendar table_. If you google calendar table, DAX, turnover you'll find this has all been done before. You just need to decide whether to do it in DAX or SQL

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Appreciate the reply. "With regards to mixing up yearly and monthly rates: how does it need to be visualised? If it doesn't need to be on the same chart/table then two seperate queries is probably fine." - After further review, I think separating the year and monthly rates would be ideal. So two separate queries is the right move. The column I'm stuck on though, that I can't figure out is how to calculate the active number at the end of a month. How can I define the exact end of a month and get the active up to that point?

Comment: "How can I define the exact end of a month and get the active up to that point?" Assuming you want the active at the end of the month, You basically need a calendar table, which has a list of all end of month dates, and you left join that on `CalendarTable.Date BETWEEN DateOfHire AND ISNULL(TermDate,'2100-01-01')`. Then you get a list of every end of month date, every person who is active on that date. Then you just count that

Comment: There are many online articles about calendar tables. Based on your requirements you probably only need a monlthy - one row for every month, with a start and end date. Then you can add some attributes that will help you with your year end calcs

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I decided to make the calendar table in SQL. This is completely new to me. I've heard of tables created as variables, but I never needed to use them until now. I did some googling and found one that I've modified, I put it above. So the range it provides will work. But I don't understand in the slightest how it works or how to integrate it with my existing data like you've outlined above. There are plenty of resources that explain how to make it, but I couldn't find any that explain the logic of combining it with an existing dataset. If you know of any I'd be grateful.

Comment: It's in my prior comment - you left join the calendar to your from/to tablre and it'll spit out a count per period. I'll post an answer shortly addressing just this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the general concept, given the things you have posted so far

### Set up sample hire and termination data

Note that answering a question is much easier if you've provided this in your question beforehand!

```
DECLARE @Sample table ([Location] VARCHAR(20), DateOfHire DATETIME, TermDate DATE, PayrollNo INT)

INSERT INTO @Sample ([Location] , DateOfHire , TermDate, PayrollNo)
VALUES 
('Camp Lucas','1999-12-27','2017-01-03',1),
('Burger King','2000-01-04','1900-01-01',2),
('The Swamp','2001-08-03','1900-01-01',3),
('The Swamp','2000-04-07','1900-01-01',4),
('The Swamp','2013-07-01','2017-07-01',5),
('Burger King','2016-02-01','2019-07-01',6),
('Camp Lucas','2000-06-12','2013-04-01',7),
('Camp Lucas','2008-08-01','2015-10-29',8)
```

### Set up calendar table

Note:
You'll use this frequently enough to make it a real table, Calendar tables often contain things like local holidays, I've added some other flags to the table that just make date calculations so much easier

```
 DECLARE @Calendar table
 (
     [CalendarDate] DATE,
     CalendarMonth VARCHAR(7),
     IsSOM bit,
     IsEOM bit,
     IsSOY bit,
     IsEOY bit
 )

 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
 DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
 SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
 SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

 WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO @Calendar
             (
                    CalendarDate,
                    CalendarMonth,
                    IsSOM,
                    IsEOM,
                    IsSOY,
                    IsEOY
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate,
                   FORMAT(@StartDate,'yyyy-MM'),
                   CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,@StartDate)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsSOM,
                   CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate))=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsEOM,
                   CASE WHEN FORMAT(@StartDate,'ddMM')='0101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsSOY,
                   CASE WHEN FORMAT(@StartDate,'ddMM')='3112' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsEOY

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @StartDate)
      END
```

### Do the magic

Now we use the calendar as the driving table - we always want a record even if there are zero people hired so we use a left join to the hire table.

We use `between` to match records. So if a single record in the hire table describes a person that was hired, then terminated 40 days later, this will result in 40 records for that person, one record on each day they were employed.

Then we do some "conditional aggregates" which inspect various things inside those (for example) 40 records. Then we sum that up and group by month and location

```
SELECT 
C.CalendarMonth, 
S.Location, 
-- When calculating Headcount at end of month, 
-- only consider a record on the end of the month
SUM(CASE WHEN IsEOM=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EOMHeadcount,

-- Similar logic for start of month
SUM(CASE WHEN IsSOM=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOMHeadcount,

-- To count Terminations, only count records 
-- on days that there was a termination
SUM(CASE WHEN C.CalendarDate = S.TermDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PeriodTerminations,

-- Similar logic for Hires
SUM(CASE WHEN C.CalendarDate = S.DateOfHire THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PeriodHires
FROM 
@Calendar C
LEFT JOIN 
@Sample S
ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN S.DateOfHire AND IIF(S.TermDate = '1900-01-01','2100-01-01',S.TermDate)
GROUP BY C.CalendarMonth, S.Location
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Have a crack and get back to me with any questions.

Comment: I really really appreciate this. I see how you added flags if the day is the start or end of month. That makes a lot sense. I've plugged in my data, but when I run it, it runs seemingly 'forever.' If I stop it, it spits out '(1 row affected)' many times. I posted mine at the end of the question post. Did I miss renaming something or something? I'm sure I just missed something.

Comment: How many rows are in your Employee table? Is there any indexes on DateOfHire or TermDate? This can generate a lot of rows. If you have 3,000 people employed for 600 days that 1,800,000 rows it has to initially generate before needing to aggregate.

Comment: Also table variables are generally not good for performance. Proper tables generally work better.

Comment: That was it. It was the total number of employee records. It needed more time. I had also forgotten to reduce the total records with my contractid in the where clause. This is an above and beyond answer. This helps me specifically address my query and it turns a foreign concept into something easy to digest since I can watch it work with other data I'm already familiar with.